# How to send email with attachment using Mail::mailer in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-8

How to send email for multiple recipient and multiple attachment using Laravel Mail::Mailer?

For single email below code works well. Now i need to add multiple recipient and multiple attachments needs to add.

`Mail::mailer('Info')->to($request['emailto'])->send(new ComposeEmail($subject, $data));`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#looping-over-recipients ?

Comment: Yes but i need to use specific mailer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
    Mail::mailer('Info')->to($recipient['emailto'])->send(new ComposeEmail($subject, $data));
}
```

and to attach multiple files;
from ComposeEmail add this.

```
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
   $email->attach($attachment) //url to file
}
```

assuming you have $email = $this->from()->to()->subject();